# Get data from setOnItemClickListener and pass another activity

Tags: android

I have a listview and a SQL database. In my SQL database, there is a `title` and a `content` field. I display `titles` on a listview. Now this is what I'm trying to achieve: When I click the title, this should pass me to another activity and in this activity I want to see relative `content` in edittext. And sorry for my poor English.

This is my code.
**DB CLASS.**

```
public class NoteAlDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


private static final String VERITABANI_ISMI = "veritabanim2.db";
private static final int VERITABANI_VERSION = 1;
private static final String TABLO_ISMI = "noteAlTablosu";


public static final String ID = "_id";
public static final String NOTEBASLIK= "noteTitle";
public static final String NOTEICERIK = "noteContent";


final Context c;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public NoteAlDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, VERITABANI_ISMI, null, VERITABANI_VERSION);
    this.c = context;
}



@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String tablo_olustur = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLO_ISMI +
            " ("+ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
            NOTEBASLIK + " TEXT, " +
            NOTEICERIK + " TEXT);";

    db.execSQL(tablo_olustur);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST " + TABLO_ISMI);
    onCreate(db);

}

public NoteAlDatabase abrirBaseDeDatos() throws SQLException {
   NoteAlDatabase noteAlDatabase = new NoteAlDatabase(c);
    noteAlDatabase.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}


public long addReminder(NoteAlModel noteAl) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(ID, noteAl.getNoteAlID());
    cv.put(NOTEBASLIK, noteAl.getNoteAlBaslik());
    cv.put(NOTEICERIK, noteAl.getNoteAlIcerik());
    // tarih'te eklenecek /long cinsinden

    long id = db.insert(TABLO_ISMI,null,cv);
    db.close();

    return id;
}




public List<NoteAlModel> AllData() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String[] sutunlar = new String[]{ID,NOTEBASLIK,NOTEICERIK};

    Cursor c =db.query(TABLO_ISMI, sutunlar,null,null,null,null,null);

    int idsirano = c.getColumnIndex(ID);
    int basliksirano = c.getColumnIndex(NOTEBASLIK);
    int iceriksirano = c.getColumnIndex(NOTEICERIK);

    List<NoteAlModel> liste = new ArrayList<NoteAlModel>();

    for (c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){

        NoteAlModel noteAlModel = new NoteAlModel();

        noteAlModel.setNoteAlID(c.getString(idsirano));
        noteAlModel.setNoteAlBaslik(c.getString(basliksirano));
        noteAlModel.setNoteAlIcerik(c.getString(iceriksirano));

        liste.add(noteAlModel);
    }

    db.close();

    return liste;

}


public void Sil(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLO_ISMI, null, null);
}
```

**ListViewActivity:**

```
     public class NoteListele extends AppCompatActivity {
     ListView listView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_note_listele);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnYeniNotKaydet);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(NoteListele.this, NoteAlActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


  try {
        displayListview();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(NoteListele.this, "Listelenecek veri bulunmamakta", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }
    });

}



    public void displayListview() {
    NoteAlDatabase db = new NoteAlDatabase(getApplicationContext());
    List<NoteAlModel> liste = new ArrayList<NoteAlModel>();
    liste = db.AllData();
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<NoteAlModel>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, liste);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}

public void deleteAllData(View view) {
    NoteAlDatabase db = new NoteAlDatabase(getApplicationContext());
    db.Sil();
    //displayListview();
}
```

**GETSET Model:**

```
public class NoteAlModel {

private String noteAlID;
private String noteAlBaslik;
private  String noteAlIcerik;

public NoteAlModel() {
}


public NoteAlModel(String noteAlID, String noteAlBaslik, String noteAlIcerik) {
    this.noteAlID = noteAlID;
    this.noteAlBaslik = noteAlBaslik;
    this.noteAlIcerik = noteAlIcerik;
}

public NoteAlModel(String noteAlBaslik, String noteAlIcerik) {
    this.noteAlBaslik = noteAlBaslik;
    this.noteAlIcerik = noteAlIcerik;
}

public String getNoteAlID() {
    return noteAlID;
}

public void setNoteAlID(String noteAlID) {
    this.noteAlID = noteAlID;
}

public String getNoteAlBaslik() {
    return noteAlBaslik;
}

public void setNoteAlBaslik(String noteAlBaslik) {
    this.noteAlBaslik = noteAlBaslik;
}

public String getNoteAlIcerik() {
    return noteAlIcerik;
}

public void setNoteAlIcerik(String noteAlIcerik) {
    this.noteAlIcerik = noteAlIcerik;
}
```

logcat

```
03-06 20:16:46.095 4886-4886/reminderplus.reminder2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: reminderplus.reminder2, PID: 4886
                                                                  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method AllData()Landroid/database/Cursor; in class Lreminderplus/reminder2/veritabani/NoteAlDatabase; or its super classes (declaration of 'reminderplus.reminder2.veritabani.NoteAlDatabase' appears in /data/data/reminderplus.reminder2/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9_4376acd355cb0a9e536cff445d1b4b60f3d0940d-classes.dex)
                                                                      at reminderplus.reminder2.noteal.NoteListele.onCreate(NoteListele.java:46)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not to convert your `Cursor` into `List<NoteAlModel>`. You can use `Cursor` with `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

In this case your `AllData` Method will look like:

```
public Cursor AllData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] sutunlar = new String[]{ID,NOTEBASLIK,NOTEICERIK};
    Cursor c = db.query(TABLO_ISMI, sutunlar,null,null,null,null,null);
    db.close();
    return c;
  }
```

Then you create a `SimpleCursorAdapter` and set it to your `ListView`

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
    db.AllData(), 
    new String[] { NoteAlDatabase.NOTEBASLIK }, 
    new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
listView.setAdapter(scAdapter);
```

After that you have a `ListView` with your "titles" and now let's manage your `setOnItemClickListener` to open a "content" in new activtiy.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String content = ((SimpleCursorAdapter)parent.getAdapter()).
                        getCursor().getString(NoteAlDatabase.NOTEICERIK);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ContentActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("PARAM", content);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

And now you can obtain the content in `ContentActivity`'s onCreate method

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_content);

    //...
    String content = getIntent().getExtras().getString("PARAM", "");
    // show content in some `TextView`
}
```

Comment: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{reminderplus.reminder2/reminderplus.reminder2.noteal.NoteListele}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor reminderplus.reminder2.veritabani.NoteAlDatabase.AllData()' on a null object reference` I get this error, when I clicked the listviewdisplay activity.

Comment: please provide the full logcat error above. It seems, that you call AllData() on null object. Did you create NoteAlDatabase db object before?

Comment: did you change your AllData() method? it should return Cursor now

Comment: I did not change method.

Comment: I did. I copied your code and pasted in my code but I get this logcat error.

Comment: please provide your NoteListele->onCreate method. do you create a db object before AllData() call?

Comment: `SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,db.AllData(),
                new String[]{NoteAlDatabase.NOTEBASLIK},
                new int[]{android.R.id.text1});
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);`  I added `Log.d`. And app give me error this section. `No virtual method AllData()`. Ahh I'm sad man. It is possible if I upload my app and you check the issues?

Comment: it would be helpful! do you have a github?

Comment: I have but I can't upload more than 100 files on GitHub. I upload on [MediaFire](http://www.mediafire.com/download/xh7dpp0i4a6b61h/Reminder2.rar)

Comment: I'm sorry, dude, but you have many problems in your code. I would like to advice you to read something about ContentProvider and use it with your DB.